# Why is there a visible gap between adjacent DIVs on iOS Safari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

After pulling all my hair out it has come down to this minimal html page that seems to be rendering wrongly on iOS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

#fold
{
    background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/gigantt_pub_imgs/2012/07/1342078193.png) top left;
    min-height:350px;
}


#features
{
    background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/gigantt_pub_imgs/2012/07/1342078193.png) top left;
    min-height:350px;       
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fold">
    </div>
    <div id="features">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When viewing in iOS (or for that matter in the iOS simulator) you can see a while line between the two blue divs.

[image]

This white line disappears if you zoom in. And of course it's not visible in any other desktop browser I've tried, either.

So, am I going nuts or is anybody else getting this? Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Did You ever found solution? Asked 11 years ago, and this nightmare still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be construed as a bug (I think it is) - but it has to do with the way [iOS handles background images](http://stevegardner.net/2011/05/31/fix-for-gaps-in-background-images-on-iphone-and-ipad/).

The quick answer - add a negative margin to one of your elements. [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPR4H/6/).

The relevant portion is this:

```
#features
{
    background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/gigantt_pub_imgs/2012/07/1342078193.png) top left;
    min-height:350px;
    margin-top: -2px;    
}
```

You can target this using media queries.

Comment: What shall I do if the patterns have to be seamless and I can't have them overlap?

Comment: I would still use media queries to target devices with retina resolution, and a max width of 768 (e.g. iOS devices) and set the margin top within there. You might have to experiment with the values of the margin to get it to look right.

Answer (score 1):

This solved issue on iphone gap only for me.

```
#features
{
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;    
}
```

And yes its 2023 and iphone is still broken as ever.
Adding only margin would cut of the image, so with two adjacent images You could see the cut. But when adding 1px border, and going -1px margin to hide that border, this annoying gap somehow dissapear. In my case I had 20 divs under each other, each had image inside, and on iphone there were random tiny gaps between them .. This solved that. Was impossible to simulate in chrome debugger, gaps are visible when zoom is forced in debuger but no solution works for debugger. This works ok for android also, didnt catch any problems, apart that last image has border at bottom but that can be solved by "last-child" css. Cant belive this took half year of trial and error.