# Random line shows up in mobile, but not desktop

Tags: css, mobile

So I'm developing a mobile site, and I've run across an issue where a random line pops up above a section. I can't really test it, because the line doesn't show up on desktop. I'm using a brand new Android phone with ICS, and I've tested it on a few other phones as well.

[image]

My HTML structure is:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer-top">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-main">
    </div>
</footer>
```

My CSS for those sections is:

```
footer { margin-top: -18px; position: relative; z-index: 100; }
.footer-top { background: url(../images/footer-top.png) repeat center top; height: 35px; text-align: center; }
.footer-main { background: url(../images/footer_bg.jpg) repeat center; padding-bottom: 30px;}
```

I just can't find a reason why that line would appear. Has anyone else run across a problem like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I think this may be a webkit-wide issue, though I thought it was just an iOS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450934/is-this-an-ios-safari-css-bug/11452955#11452955).

Basically, it's a rendering bug. You might have to give one of your div's a negative margin of 1 or 2 pixels to get it to go away. You can target this using media queries, so desktop will be unaffected.

Comment: This is a solely mobile site, so I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Definitely a gross fix, but it worked. I had to bring 2 backgrounds and an image up by a pixel. I hate negative margins haha.

Comment: Ugh, I hear ya. I've seen it crop up in some places, and not in others. Not sure why. Glad it worked!